# Updating a stock count between two Excel worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

Ok guys, I'm sure this is dead simple but it's got me flummoxed. Two sheets inside a workbook
I have an inventory list on the first sheet with 272 lines. This list has 7 columns and the first column lists part numbers (made into a table), the last column H has the stock counts.

The second, let's call it a Log, sheet is composed of 7 columns where the first column permits a drop-down list of any item and the second column has a field entry of the quantity taken. The 4th column is the date field.

What formula can I insert to make the log sheet update the master list whenever an item is taken, so that we always have an accurate count? It would be nice if There is a formula so that when someone finishes their line entry, either the line auto-saves or auto-saves after ~2 minutes, or they can press a button (I've already made a button with Developer tab) to update the changes? Just mainly looking for a good way to build in a proper count function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mind adding an extra column in your first sheet? Or do you want to update it automatically in the first sheet after you press a button?

Comment: Surely, a better solution would be to migrate away from Excel to a database-driven solution where each product is its own record and it contains the stock levels? You can then use Excel to interrogate your database if you need to do any stats?

Comment: @Kinnectus At this stage, that would probably be overkill. It's something where I could experiment with Access, but I don't have much experience and it would probably take longer and is outside of my knowledge-level.

Comment: @Michthan I don't mind adding an extra column at all but would prefer the first sheet updates automatically when I press a button in the second (changelog). This way, any user line item entries are saved as of that point and we can consider it a reliable datapoint. Reporting export from this will likely be nil to minimal in future.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What you want to do is not "dead simple". There isn't a formula that will know when to run the calculation. There will need to be a trigger. What have you tried so far? Where are you at in the process?

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank you for the welcome. I've attempted writing some formulas and using SUM/SUMIF but am inexperienced and thus cannot seem to make this work. Perhaps if the greater SUM function were applied to the first table, referencing the first and last category (joined?) and the secondary sheet were part of the IF clause, I suppose something could be fashioned, but that's as far as I have gone and am at a loss as to how to construct such an argument.

Comment: What you want is a function to find the part number in the first column of the first sheet, then in that row, make a change (based off the the value in a cell on anther sheet) to the cell containing the current stock count. Am I understanding correctly? If so, that will not be as simple as a formula. VBA will be needed to do this. Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, that's correct. I'm glad you are able to understand the request. I'm not familiar with VBA, unfortunately but am willing to work through the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only going off of your description of what you are doing, without seeing your workbook. It is a starting point for you. **Make backup copies of your file before attempting this.**

On your second sheet, create a button to the right of the last column from the Developer tab. If the developer tab is not available, [go here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45) to learn how to make it visible.

[image]

Right click the button and choose `View Code`. A window will open and you will see something like this in the right pane.

[image]

In between the two lines, paste the following code.

```
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim strPart As String

'Find last row in the log
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Get the part number and amount taken from the last row
strPart = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LastRow).Value
intCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & LastRow).Value

'Look for a match in the first sheet
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strPart, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0)

'Subtract the amount from the count
intCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & lRow).Value - intCount
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & lRow).Value = intCount
```

After you have pasted it, you will need to change the sheet names if yours are not the default `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. Sheet1 is where your inventory list is. Sheet2 is the log that takes away from the inventory.

Close the VBA window and right click the button and choose `Properties`. Change the caption to "Calculate", or something else descriptive, and close. **DO NOT** change the `(name)` at the top or your button will not work.

Click `Design Mode` in the menu to make the button active.

Provided when you refer to the first column and the second column you meant column `A` and `B`, this will find the part number in the last row of the log, then match it to the part number in the other sheet and then subtract the taken amount from the inventory.

It only calculates the last row. It will not do any previous rows. SO, if there are already existing rows or you forget to click the button after you enter the data, it will be missed. On the flip side, if you hit the button more than once, it will subtract as many times as you hit the button.

This should get you headed in the right direction. Alternatively, you can do this with a button in the Ribbon instead of on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to enter all the starting totals for the 272 items on Sheet 1 into the data on Sheet 2. Preferrably before the actual inventory changes, but it is not essential to the functionality.

Then Sheet 2's inventory change column gets positive entries for additions and negative entries for removals. An alternative would be to expand Sheet 2's column usage to have a second column for inventory changes and use one for additions and one for removals which has an advantage in that one would use positive values in each.

Finally, Sheet 1's inventory level column (H) would have a simple `SUMIF()` formula that, in the simple version, sums all the items in Sheet 2's inventory change column that match the part # to the formula's left (column A) on Sheet 1. The more complicated idea (two inventory related columns, one for additions, one for removals) would do the same with the formula using the additions column but would use a second `SUMIF()` for the removals but place a "-" before the `SUMIF()` so the formula actually subtracts them (in the simple version, the removals all had their own "-" in their entries so this was not necessary... not helpful, for that matter!).

Now this doesn't save the file each time, but as you wrote about "saving" it seemed fairly clear you really meant making sure that information was saved and acted upon immediately. The above does that.

Comment: You should provide an example.